# perfect square of summation of odd numbers

Tags: elementary-number-theory, square-numbers

This is not homework  , and I am old enough to be your father :-).We know the summation of odd numbers results in perfect squares , like $1 + 3 = 4 $, $1+ 3 + 5 = 9$ and so on.

My  question is , if we start from a random odd number (say $315$) , how many odd numbers after $315$ results in a perfect square ? For what odd number $(2n-1)$ does :-   $315 + 317 + 319 + .....(2n-1) = x^2 $ occur for $ n,x \in \mathbb{N} $ , and $(2n-1)> 315$ ?

Comment: Another way of stating the same problem is through difference of squares. Since $1 + 3 + ... + 313$ is a perfect square, and $1 + 3 + ... + (2n-1) = n^2$ is also a perfect square, what is $n$ such that the difference of these two numbers is also a perfect square?

Comment: yes , summation of the range starting with 315 results in a perfect square

Comment: There are two parameters to the problem - the starting point and the number of odd numbers you sum up. For instance, if you start at the $(k+1)^{st}$ odd number and add up $n$ odd numbers, your sum is $(k+n)^2-k^2 = n(2k+n)$, which needs to be a perfect square. In your example, $k=158$, i.e. 315 is the $158^{th}$ odd number. So our sum is $n(n+316)$. I used a computer to look from $n=1$ to $n=100000$ and found $n=6084$ as one possible answer. So if you start at 315 and add up the next 6084 odd numbers, so create the square of 6240. Not sure how to come up with a general rule :)

Comment: Number of terms: $12168$. Last term: $24649$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We know that the sum up to $2k-1$ is $k^2$, so the sum up to $313$ is $157^2$.  If the highest number in your sum is $2n-1$ we then are asking that $$n^2-157^2=x^2\\(n+x)(n-x)=157^2$$
There will be a solution for each way of factoring $157^2$ into two numbers of the same parity, so both must be odd.  As $157$ is prime, the only factorization of interest is $1,157^2$ 
$$n+x=157^2\\n-x=1\\n=\frac 12(1+157^2)=12325\\x=12324$$

Comment: No, the sum $$(2\cdot 0 +1)+(2\cdot1+1)+\ldots+(2\cdot n +1)=(n+1)^2$$, not $n^2$. E.g, $1+3+5=3^2$

Comment: I think that there is a little mistake is the sum up to $2k+1$, $k^2$? Or $(k+1)^2$

Comment: @RhysHughes:  yes, I realized that.  Fixed.

Answer (score 2):

We have:- $ 315+317+...(2n-1)=x^2 \implies n^2 - 157^2 = x^2 \implies x^2 + 157^2 = n^2 $

This is a [Pythagorean Triple](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_triple) !

By setting $157 = k\cdot(p^2 - q^2) = k\cdot(p+q)(p-q) $ , we can obtain our values . However , $157$ is a prime number , and thus , $$p+q=157$$ $$p-q=1$$ $$k=1$$ Thus , $p=79$ and $ q= 78 $

Also , $n=k\cdot(p^2+q^2)=79^2+78^2=12325$ , and $x=2kpq=2\cdot 78 \cdot 79 = 12324 $

Answer (score 0):

Lets suppose that the random odd number in which we stop is $2k+1$. We known that the sum: 
$$1+3+5+\cdots +(2k+1) = k^2$$

Consider two cases:

Case 1: k is even

If this is the case then que can write $k = 2n$. Follows to see that $k^2 = (2n)^2$ and,

$$(2n)^2+(n^2-1)^2 = (n^2+1)^2$$

We know that:

$$1+3+4+\cdots+(2(n^2+1)+1)$$

Hence is follows that:
$$(n^2+1)^2-(2n)^2 = (2k+3) + (2k+5)+\cdots + (2(n^2+1)+1) = (n^2-1)^2$$

To sum up: if k is even, then the sum from $2k+3$ to $2(\frac{k^2}{4} + 1)+1$ going only from odd to odd gives a perfect square.

Case 2: k is odd

We can express k as $2n+1$ and then it can easily be seen that:

$$(2n+1)^2+(2n^2+2n)^2 = (2n^2+2n+1)^2$$

Hence, by the same reasoning than before:

$$(2k+3)+(2k+5)+\cdots + (2(2n^2+2n+1)+1) = (2n^2+2n)^2$$

Meaning that the sum that goes from $2k+3$ to $2\left(2\left(\frac{k-1}{2}\right)^2+2\left(\frac{k-1}{2}\right)+1\right)+1$ is a perfect square.

This provides an answer for any odd number, but it is not the smallest possible answer. I will try to figure out how to get the smallest possible one.

Hope I was helpful